# Filter by calculated column with rest api in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: rest, filter

Apparently you can't filter by calculated column with SharePoint 2013 REST API?  The calculated column in question returns a string.

```
http://site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestList')/items?$filter=CalcCol eq 'blah'  -- does NOT work

http://site/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/TestList?$filter=CalcCol eq 'blah'  -- works
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I am surprised to find not too many questions on this problem. Thanks for posting. Let me know if you ever find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this might be a bug in 2013.

This post suggests it also doesn't work when filtering a list in the standard view.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bb184556-db23-4851-9e34-3f4497a32776/filtering-by-a-calculated-column-in-sharepoint?forum=sharepointgeneral

Answer (score -3):

You can't do it because the calculated field is not stored anywhere, it just is rendered each time you navigate to the display form.